# ElasticSearch, can't find my object after update it

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, logstash, querydsl

I have an ElasticSearch with some tweets.

When I update one field of a specific tweet:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/AVUvNhBBGGUJjR2EAFix/_update" -d '
{ 
  "script": "ctx._source.retweet_count += 5"
}'
```

I've got a success:

```
{"_index":"twitter","_type":"tweet","_id":"AVUvNhBBGGUJjR2EAFix","_version":4,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}
```

I can check my updated object with:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/AVUvNhBBGGUJjR2EAFix/_source"
```

But when I try to get all the tweets from my ElasticSearch:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search" -d '{ "query": {"match_all": {}}}'
```

**I can't find my updated object.**

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

_search show you 10 results by default. 
I simply used the size parameter to show all my results:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty=true&size=58" -d '{ "query": {"match_all": {}}}'
```

Hope that could help.